# Passing unit macro to siunitx with pythontex

Tags: siunitx, python

I want to write a macro combining `\pythontex` and `\siunitx` packages.
More precisely, I want to make calculation with (complex) numbers in python and then typeset result in `\SI{number from python}{unit}`.

I have defined a macro `\pySIC` which does (more or less) the trick. However, I have noticed strange behavior when I try to pass `unit` macro e.g. `\ampere`, `\ohm` ... as second argument.

Instead of `\ampere` I must pass `\\ampere`, whereas passing `\ohm` is OK.
Why double backslashes in case of `\\ampere`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pythontex}


\begin{pythontexcustomcode}{py}
    from scipy import *
\end{pythontexcustomcode}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\pySIC}{ m m O{}}
{%
\py{'\\SI[#3]{' + str(#1).replace('(','').replace(')','') + '}{#2}'}%
}

\begin{document}
 % defining complex number
    \pyc{Z = 1 + 1j}
    \pySIC{Z}{\\ampere}     \par
    \pySIC{Z}{\ohm}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your command definition, you need `r'}{#2}'`.  You want a raw, unescaped string.

As it is, the units macro names are being passed to Python, and then the backslashes are being treated as escapes in Python strings. `\a` becomes `\x07`, while `\o` becomes `\\o` after the escaping.